# Why am I not allowed to access files in /usr/bin/?

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, filesystems, udev

I have this machine. I am the sole user of the machine. I cannot access files in /usr/bin/ because of a location issue with `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/` and am currently receiving errors.

What would be a couple of reasons why I have no permissions for /usr/bin/ on newly installed binaries? I am asking because printrun is creating the binary in `/usr/bin/` for use in userland.

I am currently trying to access files in /usr/bin/, these binaries, and I am receiving errors of unknown locations of the files...

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/plugins/__init__.py': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/plugins/__pycache__': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/plugins/sample.py': Permission denied
```

Here is another idea of errors when running `python3 /usr/bin/pronsole` or when especially running the command `python3 /usr/bin/pronterface`.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PRINTCORE_HANDLER' from 'printrun.plugins' (unknown location)
```

I am thinking that the `(unknown location)` is due to permission errors but when I use chmod in any form or fashion, I receive the same error when:

1. I use kernels 5.10.x, 6.1.x, and mainline.
2. When I update or downgrade images to previous releases or newer builds.
   `and when...`
3. I am in "full control" of my system.

I have not used `su -` or `sudo python3 /usr/bin/pronterface` because I do not want to taint the usage of my current user permissions and settings with running as a superuser.

So, to be clear...

`/usr/bin/pronterface` on my machine requires sudo or root permissions due to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/*` not having the correct permissions on my machine.

Using sudo or being the root user works...

Comment: you're mistaken - it's `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/plugins` you don't have access to, `/usr/bin` is fine

Comment: Right and okay. I just used sudo or signed in as root but you are right. My permissions for `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/*` were not set correctly. I still cannot access some binaries in `/usr/bin/`. Is this associated w/ the permission issue in the /printrun/plugins/ dir?

Comment: @ForWard *"My permissions... were not set correctly"*. Were you changing permissions of `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib`, or any other system related directory? (Since you mention the use of `chmod`).

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity, yes. I tried to change ownership of `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/*` w/ `chmod a+x` and it was successful but did not do anything.

Comment: `change ownership` ... `chmod a+x` ... you mean change permissions, since that's what `chmod` does, and `a+x` won't fix an issue if you cant `read` directories or files

Comment: `I still cannot access some binaries in /usr/bin/` like which ones? what is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/binary-you-can-not-access`

Comment: @JaromandaX, `file not found` and yes change permissions is what I was trying to achieve...

Comment: well, "file not found" is NOT a permission issue, is it - what file are you looking for in `/usr/bin` - oh god, you didn't literally type `ls -l /usr/bin/binary-you-can-not-access` did you?

Comment: No, I typed and what I typed is not literally `ls -l /usr/bin/*`. I was looking for permissions in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/*`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what's going on. Is this about `/usr/bin` or `usr/lib`? Make sure to include the details you gave in the comments since comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning.

Comment: Okay...I will edit it.

Comment: @terdon , is that okay w/ an update to my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to access a file if access is prevented by the permissions on the file itself **or on any directory on the path to the file**.

Try running `namei -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/printrun/plugins/__init__.py` to see the ownerships and permissions of all the directory levels, from root to the targeted file.

To read a file, at minimum, you'll need at least a `r` permission that is applicable to your user account on the `*.py` file itself, and an `x` permission applicable to your user account on all (grand)parent directories, all the way to the root.

To easily fix the permissions of files and directories installed from `*.deb` packages, you could do an `apt reinstall` on them:

```
sudo apt reinstall printcore printrun printrun-common pronsole pronterface
```

This will not change any of the package's configuration files if you have modified them.

Comment: Thank you. I will test the command and get back to you. Thank you again for your input.

Comment: Okay...so. root:root is the obvious user:group here and that is what is on the machine even with the `reinstall` command from apt.

Comment: But if you had accidentally removed the world read permission from the files, or the world access (`x`) permission from one of the parent directories of those files, it would have caused exactly this problem. The error messages indicate you're accessing files in `/usr/bin/` just fine, but when those files are requesting stuff from `/usr/lib/python3/...`, they (and by extension your user account) have insufficient permissions to do that. `/usr/lib/python3` and its sub-directories are supposed to be readable to everyone.

Comment: Right, that is exactly what happened. I took `chmod a+x` on files without thinking. I then `chmod -x` those files when the error stayed.

Comment: If you applied `chmod -x` not just to the files, but to the directory too, that would explain the issue. The directories in `/usr/lib/python3/...` need to have permissions `drwxr-xr-x`: if the `x` permission is removed from the directory, it prevents access to any files within that directory.

Comment: Aw. Thank you for making me understand. I was trying to give you an extra point here but the site says, "You need 15+ points to give a point." Sorry. Oh and my system is basically goofed up now. I cannot describe it yet but everything seems to be root:root with user:group so far.